# Robotframework . How I handle collapsible menu?

Tags: robotframework

I try to use Click Element id=elementid in Robotframework.
I have Selenium2 Library.
I have a Menu collapsible.
See little arrow on Entity 1 on first print screen.
I try to identify the element id.
I cannot see element id when I inspect this.
I see only jotid that I do not think is the same.
So, I am not able to use click element in order to expand my menu.
I appreciate anyone's help as I am still learner.
Please see also the images of a) Code, Menu, Inspected Element

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: please don't post images of code.

Comment: sorry. thanks for let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find it using xpath, so:

> Click Element |  //li[@wuid="gx:309..."]

Answer (score 0):

jotid is not id, so you cannot locate it by id.

You could try keyword:

```
    Click Link    ENTITY 1 -Introduction
```

or find it by css:

```
    Click element    css=a[jotid='wuid:gx:4286...<the rest of it>']
```

Comment: Unfortunately no one worked. I appreciate any other suggestions